# Nested .gitignore files -- difference between /folder/* and !folder/

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the folder structure thus

```
project/
       ----A/
            ----B/
                 -1.txt
                 -2.txt
                 -.gitignore [ content is: (Line1) * (Line2) !1.txt ]
            -.gitignore [ content is: (Line1) /B/* ]
       -.gitignore [ content is: (Line1) /A/*
.git/
-.gitignore [content is: (Line1) /project/*]
```

The above does not track `1.txt` nor does it track `2.txt`

My understanding of `project/.gitignore` which contains:

```
/A/*
```

was:

Ignore everything under folder `A/` *except* for exceptions you may encounter in deeper `.gitignore`s in subfolders, for instance, due to, say `project/A/B/.gitignore` which is:

```
*
!1.txt
```

that force you to track `1.txt`. That was also my interpretation of `project/A/.gitignore` which is:

```
/B/*
```

That is, ignore everything under folder `B/` *except* for exceptions you may encounter in deeper `.gitignore`s in subfolders, for instance, due to, say `project/A/B/.gitignore`.

Since in the example above neither `1.txt` nor `2.txt` are tracked, I am unclear what the right interpretation of `/A/*` and `/B/*` mean in the context above.

Everything else being the same, the following change to `project/.gitignore` of:

```
!A/
```

tracks `1.txt` while not tracking `2.txt`.

I would like to understand clearly why `/A/*` does not work while `!A/` works in this case.

Comment: The generic command to debug ignore rules is : `git check-ignore -v path/to/file`. run it on 1.txt and 2.txt, with and without the `!A/` pattern to have a view of what rule does or doesn't make your file ignored.

Comment: @LeGEC Agreed. In this situation, that was not illuminating and hence the post. For e.g., in the `/A/*` case both text files are ignored by `.gitignore:1:/project/*` In the case of `!A/`, `1.txt` is tracked due to `project/A/B/.gitignore:2:!1.txt` while `2.txt` is untracked due to `project/A/B/.gitignore:1:*`
So, in one case, the topmost `.gitignore` is effective, while in the other, the deepest one is effective. I am unable to wrap my head around these differences.

Comment: also check what makes `project/A/B` not ignored : you must have a pattern that does that somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you provide alone is not enough to reproduce your setup :

running the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /tmp/testrepo
mkdir -p /tmp/testrepo
cd /tmp/testrepo

git init

mkdir -p project/A/B

touch project/A/B/1.txt project/A/B/2.txt

check_ignore () {
        local path=$1
        echo "--- checking $path:"
        git check-ignore -v "$path"
}

echo "# with initial .gitignore files:"

check_ignore project/A
check_ignore project/A/B
check_ignore project/A/B/1.txt
check_ignore project/A/B/2.txt

echo "!A/" >> project/.gitignore

echo
echo "# after adding '!A/' in project/.gitignore:"

check_ignore project/A
check_ignore project/A/B       # that directory is still gitignored
                               # by the '/A/*' gitignore rule
check_ignore project/A/B/1.txt # so its content is not inspected
check_ignore project/A/B/2.txt
```

I have directory `B` (in `project/A/B`) completely ignored, which makes that neither 1.txt nor 2.txt is tracked.

---

If an ignore rule matches a directory, then `git` will not descend into that directory at all and no inner `.gitignore` file can act on what is tracked within it.

So, in your case :

- the `/A/*` rule will *not* ignore directory `/A/` : `git` will inspect its content, and possibly apply rules described in `/A/.gitignore`,
- if however no rule counters the `/A/*` for `A/B`, then `B/` will be completely ignored, and neither `B/1.txt` nor `B/2.txt` will be tracked.

Such a rule can be :

- a `!B/` rule in `project/A/.gitignore`
- or a `!A/B` rule in `project/.gitignore`

---

Your sentence should be adjusted :

a `/A/*` pattern allows you to unignore files and folders *one level down* (in `A/.gitignore`), but `.gitignore` files at deeper levels will not have an impact on their own.

Comment: Ah, so to track a deep file (say, `/A/B/C/D/file_to_track`) under `/A/` while ignoring everything else under `/A/` and its subfolders, `/A/*` should be followed by `!B/` then in the immediately successively nested `.gitignore`, we can have `/C/*` in a deeper `.gitignore` again followed by `!/D/file_to_track` in an even deeper `.gitignore`.

At any point in time, `/A/*` followed by `/B/*` will immediately render everything under `/C/` untracked. 

Thank you for your explanation and help.

Answer (score 1):

See [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561253/1256452) for a flaw in your question as posed.  I'm going to ignore the flaw and plow directly into `.gitignore` rules instead.  But first, we need to consider something odd here.  There's a sort of impedance mismatch here between Git, which *does not store folders* (only files), and your OS, which *insists that files must exist inside folders*.  It's this fundamental disagreement between "how Git works" and "how your OS insists that Git should work instead" that leads to this issue.  Git has to bridge this difference, and to do that, Git makes certain compromises.

#### Background, or what you need to know before we even start

Let's look at the difference between some stored-in-Git file and some OS-stored version of that same file, assuming for the moment that we're on Windows, so that files have path names like `C:\path\to\file`.  We'll be in `C:\top\mid` and create a new Git repository here, and make a commit that has in it the following two files:

```
.gitignore
sub/file
```

To Git, that second file is a *file* named `sub/file`.  You can see this by running:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

which will list out both files.  Technically, these two files are in Git's *index* or *staging area* at this point, but Git builds commits from the index, not from what's in your working tree.  (The terms *index* and *staging area* are pretty much interchangeable.  I tend to use the shorter and less meaningful one for various reasons, when talking about the technical aspects of Git.)

Your Windows machine, by contrast, does *not* have a *file* named `sub/file`.  Instead, it has, in `C:\top\mid`, a *folder* named `sub`, and in that `sub` folder, a file named `file`.  So the full path of that file is `C:\top\mid\sub\file`.  Git knows that the repository itself is `C:\top\mid` at this point and takes that part away, and *constructs* the name `sub/file`, with *forward slash*, to update its index copy of the file, when you run `git add` as appropriate.

So Git has a sort of flat file system, with files with "folder names" embedded right in the file names, and literal forward slashes.  But the *computer's* file system has folders-and-files.  Even if we move to macOS or Linux or whatever, we still have the folder-and-file arrangement; we just now have `/top/mid/sub/file` instead of the silly drive-letter things and the annoying backwards slashes.

Since Git actually makes *new* commits by writing out, to the repository, a commit containing all the files (names and contents) as listed in the index / staging-area, our job—whenever we're doing new work—consists of updating, and maybe adding and/or removing, OS-style files in our *working tree*, but then we have to *tell Git to update its index*.  We do that part—the *hey Git, I have new stuff now* step—using `git add` and sometimes `git rm` or `git rm --cached`.  This operation tells Git to look in the working tree—the folder-and-file stuff that the OS demands we use—from which Git will assemble its internal-format, ready-to-commit "blob" objects whose hash IDs and path names Git stashes in the index / staging-area.

#### The base problem

When we run any en-masse `git add` command, like:

```
git add .
```

we're telling Git to *scan, recursively, all the folders and sub-folders we have at the current working directory*.  That is, Git will open (using the C library `opendir` function) the path `.` to read the current directory, where it will find `.gitignore` and `sub`.  Using additional OS calls if and as needed, Git will find out that `.gitignore` *is* a file, and `sub` *is* a folder, and will get `lstat` data *about* the file and folder.

Git's index—which has a third term, *cache*—contains previously-obtained `lstat` data and Git can sometimes use this to very quickly determine that, e.g., the `.gitignore` file has not been modified, and therefore there is no need to replace the index copy of `.gitignore` with a new compressed and Git-ified file.  But (with certain exceptions that have grown over time as the Git software has gotten more and more complicated), there's no entry in the index for a *folder*, so in general, Git is forced to open and read the `sub` folder, recursively, the same way it opened and read the `.` folder.

Having opened and read through `sub`, Git will find `file`, and Git will assemble the two pieces of name to get `sub/file` (even on Windows, where the OS wants to call it `sub\file`).  As usual, the cached lstat data may or may not enable Git to quickly skip opening, reading, compressing, and generally Git-ify-ing the `sub/file` content.  If not, Git opens and reads and compresses it, and checks to see if that content is already present anywhere in any commit anywhere in the repository.

All of this scanning and opening and reading is *very slow*.  So for files that shouldn't be added, we prevent Git from bothering by listing their names in `.gitignore`.  That's great for *files*—but for every folder in `mid`, Git has to open and read it, and for every sub-folder within that folder, Git has to open and read it, and so on recursively.  Since Git is pretty well optimized, it turns out that this recursive scan of the directories is often the slowest part of `git add`.

To make this go *much* faster, Git tries to be clever.  Suppose that we'll ultimately *ignore* everything in `sub2` due to a line like `sub2/**` or `sub2/*` or `sub2/`.  Then instead of *opening and reading* the folder `sub2`, Git can simply skip it entirely!

So, Git does that: if we tell Git that some *directory* aka *folder* should be ignored, Git skips opening and reading it entirely.  This means that any files within that directory—even `.gitignore` files in it—are never even *seen*, and hence can't be obeyed.

That means that if you want Git to get into some directory (folder) to *scan* it, that part of the path, starting at `.` (corresponding to `top/mid` in our case) *must not be ignored*.  Once it's *not* ignored, Git commits to opening and reading it, including any `.gitignore` file it contains.  The rules *within* that `.gitignore` file are then temporarily added to the top level `.gitignore` and/or `.git/info/exclude` and/or `core.excludesFile` ignore rules (with higher priority, but forcibly limited to this sub-directory) while doing the recursive scan.

#### More detail

Keeping the above in mind—those rules cover what Git *sees*, and if Git doesn't *see* something, it can't possibly `git add` it—we now get to the individual `.gitignore`-file rules:

- An entry can be a simple name or glob like `sub2` or `*`.
- An entry can be *prefixed* with a slash, or *contain* a slash, such as `/sub2` or `sub2/path`.  Parts of this can use glob characters like `*` or `**` (with `**` nominally meaning *match across directories / folders*, vs a single `*` that won't cross over a slash character).
- An entry can be prefixed with `!`, making it negated.  For `!` to mean negation it must be the very first character, so if you want to prefix with both `!` and `/` you must write `!/`, not `/!`.
- An entry can *end* with `/`.  This final slash has a particular meaning and doesn't affect the "prefixed with" or "contains" slash stuff.

The stuff about slashes, excluding those final slash characters, gets a bit messy.  I like to use the terms *anchored* and *un-anchored* to distinguish between these: a name like `sub2` or pattern like `*` is *un-anchored*, but a name like `sub2/path` or `/sub2` or `/*` is *anchored*.  However, `*/` is *not* anchored since the slash is the last character.

The *final* slash, if present, means "only if this is a directory".  So `sub2/` means "sub2, but only if sub2 is actually a directory" and `*/` means "everything, but only if it's a directory".

Now we get into how Git views these ignore rules.  Remember, at the point that Git is scanning through some directory (folder) like `.` or `sub`, it's already read in the appropriate `.gitignore` file and has converted the rules to the internal form, so that it knows:

- this rule applies only to directories, or not (had a trailing `/` which is now removed);
- this rule is anchored, or not (did or didn't have another `/`);
- is negated, or not (did or didn't start with `!` which is now removed);
- in which level the `.gitignore` appeared (e.g., was it `sub/.gitignore` or `sub2/.gitignore`?—this information can technically be compressed down to a single integer indicating how deep we are in the recursive traversal, but you can think of it as a path, if that makes it easier to think about).

Git now reads each entry *in* the directory, one at a time.  Each entry names either a file—including a symbolic link, which Git treats "as if" it were a file whose contents are the symlink target—or is a folder/directory.  (On systems like Linux that have "socket files" and "device special files" and the like, if Git encounters one, it just skips over it and pretends it's not there—Git can't deal with these.)

Having read the entry's name, Git has both the short and simple name (`file` or `d.ext` for instance) and the constructed full path (`sub/file`, if we're reading `sub`, or `sub2/a/b/c/d.ext` or whatever, if we're reading `sub2/b/c` for instance).  Git now checks to see if the entry *matches*, which depends on the anchored-ness:

- If the entry is *not* anchored, it matches if the simple name (`file` or `d.ext`) matches this unanchored rule, provided that any "must be a directory" thing matches.
- If the entry *is* anchored, the full path name must match the anchored rule, excluding whatever part gets excluded based on depth.  For instance if we're looking in `sub2/b/c` and there's a `sub2/b/.gitignore` that says `c/d.ext`, we match here if this is `d.ext`, but not if the entry says `x/d.ext`: the part we take away from the full path is `sub2/b/` since that's where the `.gitignore` rule came from).

[Note that `**` matching gets kind of complicated here, and occasionally the (quite hairy) `.gitignore` code that tries to speed this up gets this wrong in test releases.  The internal test suite for Git has gotten complicated to try to catch such bugs.]

If the entry *doesn't* match, we move on.  If it *does* match, it gets remembered, and we move on.  We do this for every `.gitignore` entry, and take the *last* match, whatever that is, or we have no match.

If we have no match, the file or directory is *not* ignored.  We'll consider `git add`-ing it if it's a file, or recursively scanning it.

If we have a match, the file or directory *is* ignored unless it's a negated rule: for a negated rule we pretend we didn't have a match.

That's the whole set of rules.  Note that there are no exceptions for, e.g., "there's a rule that says don't bother reading `sub2` even though there's an additional negated rule that says to keep `sub2/important.file`".  I'd argue that Git should do this automatically for you, at least for constant strings (glob matchers like `*` and `**` might make it too hard).

#### Some general helpful hints

The usual problem is that Git ignores a directory we want it to search.  We can—at a cost—tell Git *never ignore any directory at all* with the simple rule:

```
!*/
```

That's a negated, un-anchored rule.  Putting this as the *last* entry in each `.gitignore` means that Git will search all the sub-directories it finds at this level, or any lower level that didn't override this rule with its own `.gitignore`.

This completely defeats the (sometimes very important) optimization that lets Git not scan entire sub-trees of files.

A more targeted trick is that, if there's some path:

```
!keep/this/important.file
```

you can prefix that with:

```
!keep/
!keep/this/
```

to make sure that Git searches inside `keep`, and then `keep/this/`, assuming `keep/.gitignore` does not exist or does not override the `keep/this/` entry.

Comment: thank you, as always, for your deep answers and help. I will, as always :-), take a few days to digest the material you have posted.